# Symfony 4 site, after composer update, now stuck in update loop of PHP Fatal Errors?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I've a Symfony 4.0.8 site.

A few days ago, all was working.  Since that time, I've made NO code or config changes.

I *have* run a number of both 'composer' and 'yarn' updates.

Currently, I'm unable to update or access the site.

I'm stuck in a "PHP fatal error" composer update loop -- and, iiuc, there's a problem with autoloading.

Here's what I'm seeing

```
cat composer.json
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    ...

composer dump-autoload
    Generating autoload files

composer clear-cache
    Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
    Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir): 
    Clearing cache (cache-repo-dir): /root/.composer/cache/repo
    Clearing cache (cache-files-dir): /root/.composer/cache/files
    Clearing cache (cache-dir): /root/.composer/cache

redis-cli flushall
    OK

composer update
        1/1:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$ab716f1fe302ba4a374535db44b1ad22b3e9b9030c6e62892e9a7afac81b8c74.json
        Finished: success: 1, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 1
    Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

    Prefetching 7 packages 
      - Downloading (100%)

    Package operations: 7 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
      - Installing friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle (dev-master 6b75eba): Loading from cache
      - Installing snc/redis-bundle (dev-master b133296): Loading from cache
      - Installing solarium/solarium (4.0.0-rc.1): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/block-bundle (dev-master 952b171): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/menu-bundle (dev-master 5c6bd22): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle (dev-master ab9fa1d): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/tree-browser-bundle (dev-master 14ddf7d): Loading from cache
    Writing lock file
    Generating autoload files
    ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
    ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
    Executing script cache:clear [OK]
    Executing script assets:install --symlink --relative public [OK]
    Executing script security-checker security:check [OK]

composer update
    Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
    Writing lock file
    Generating autoload files
    ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
    ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
    Executing script cache:clear [KO]
     [KO]
    Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
    !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "CmfMenuBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle".
    !!  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /opt/test/src/Kernel.php:32
    !!  Stack trace:
    !!  #0 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(403): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
    !!  #1 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
    !!  #2 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(64): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
    !!  #3 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(143): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(S in /opt/test/src/Kernel.php on line 32
    !!  
    Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

composer update
    Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Package operations: 7 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
      - Installing friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle (dev-master 6b75eba): Loading from cache
      - Installing snc/redis-bundle (dev-master b133296): Loading from cache
      - Installing solarium/solarium (4.0.0-rc.1): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/block-bundle (dev-master 952b171): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/menu-bundle (dev-master 5c6bd22): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle (dev-master ab9fa1d): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony-cmf/tree-browser-bundle (dev-master 14ddf7d): Loading from cache
    Writing lock file
    Generating autoload files
    ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
    ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
    Executing script cache:clear [OK]
    Executing script assets:install --symlink --relative public [OK]
    Executing script security-checker security:check [OK]

composer update
    Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
    Writing lock file
    Generating autoload files
    ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
    ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
    Executing script cache:clear [KO]
     [KO]
    Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
    !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "CmfMenuBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle".
    !!  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /opt/test/src/Kernel.php:32
    !!  Stack trace:
    !!  #0 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(403): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
    !!  #1 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
    !!  #2 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(64): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
    !!  #3 /opt/test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(143): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(S in /opt/test/src/Kernel.php on line 32
    !!
    Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

Removing/disabling Bundles isn't the solution here -- again, everything was recently working, with all current bundles installed.

'Something' in that number of composer/yarn upgrades is causing this.

The question's what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the error states "class "CmfMenuBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle"" it seems that there is some type of problem with CmfMenuBundle update.

Modify your composer.json to specify that your project should use the previous version of the cmfMenuBundle, then run the composer install command which should install the specific version specified.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, removing/disabling Bundles isn't the solution here; Bundle versions are, apparently, also irrelevant.

Turns out the problem is current composer release, v1.6.4.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7268

Drop back to composer v1.6.3 cures all.